# Extract emails from HTML by using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, selectnodes

How can I extract the email and website address using HtmlAgilityPack in this HTML code :

```
<a class="email" href="mailto:babaie@irandoc.ac.ir">

<a class="" href="http://www.babaie.ir" target="_blank">www.babaie.ir</a>
```

I tried this code but it doesn't work for email :

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href= ' ' ]");
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 7):

Getting email:

```
var a = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@class='email']");
if (a != null)
{
    string href = a.Attributes["href"].Value; // TODO: Check if href exists
    string email = href.Replace("mailto:", "");
}
```

It's not clear how your website address differs from any other anchor tags (no specific class or id here), so following code will return all `href` links from any anchors in your html:

```
var urls = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
              .Select(a => a.Attributes["href"].Value)
              .Where(href => !href.StartsWith("mailto:")) // skip emails
              .ToList();
```